# MS Office Mobile Digital Signature

Tags: xamarin, ms-office, digital-signature

I want to apply a digital signature (using a certificate) to office files. This is possible on the desktop version of MS Office:

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Add-or-remove-a-digital-signature-in-Office-files-70d26dc9-be10-46f1-8efa-719c8b3f1a2d#__toc311526848

I need to do this on the mobile version of MS Office, but it is disabled. Does anyone know why I can’t sign with this certificate on a mobile device? Is there any mobile API for MS Office that allows to apply digital signatures?

Second option is to develop dedicated app in Xamarin. Anyone know if using Xamarin framework is possible to apply digital signatures for office documents?

Comment: Why was this question down voted. It seems valid to me.

Answer (score 0):

MS Word desktop uses the capi or capi ng api for signing. But it is not supported by word Mobile (or word for office 365)

A solution is to digitally sign with CoSign. See www.arx.com  We can sign word documents in native word format.

We have network APIs that can be used for this from mobile.  Our mobile clients use them.

Disclosure: I work for them